# Sound and heat when lid is closed - MacBook Air

Tags: audio, macbook-pro

Can you damage screen or something because of:

- Playing loud music when lid is down?
- Running some processor/videocard-intensive applications that heat the laptop, while lid is down?

Comment: Did you ever choose an answer? Did you find out more information? I would like to know if heat is an issue with a Macbook Pro (early 20122) lid closed.

Comment: @webworm unfortunately, I haven't find anything on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Playing loud music? I doubt it. The sound probably won't sound as good (as it'll be muffled), but it'll work.

Heat? Maybe. I have an older MacBook Pro that gets its airflow in through the speaker grilles and out through the hinge. I don't run it when closed for that reason, but that is supported (it wasn't on my even older iBook G4). If you can wake it up with the lid closed, it'll probably work fine. Try it a few times and see if the screen is uncomfortably hot after a half hour or 45 minutes.